# Redim Preserve on multi-dimensional array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm having problems with resizing a 2 dimensional array with redim preserve.
I know that you can only resize the second dimension and I'm sure that's what I'm doing.

What I'm doing: 
I have 2 sheets of similar data, called Oracle1 & Oracle 2
I basically want to end up with Oracle1 data as is, and then check each row of Oracle2 data and if it's not in Oracle1, add it to the end of the data.
(Doing this without arrays is very simple but slow for the 8000+ rows in each sheet)

So in the test code snippet below I load the ranges I need into 2 dynamic arrays, and transpose the ranges as I do this to ensure that I can resize the array to add extra data to it correctly. I only need to add one extra set of data at a time, so just want to expand it's size by 1 each time.

It fails on the redim with 'Subscript out of Range' error and I could swear I'm doing it correctly.

Help !

```
Set csht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Oracle1")
Set psht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Oracle")
Set csht2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Oracle2")   


carr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(csht2.Range("A2:N" & csht2.Cells(csht2.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row))
parr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(csht.Range("A2:N" & csht.Cells(csht.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row))

parrsize1 = UBound(parr, 1)
parrsize2 = UBound(parr, 2)

ReDim Preserve parr(parrsize1 To parrsize1, parrsize2 To (parrsize2 + 1))
```

Edit:
Fixed thanks to Scott below.

Comment: `ReDim Preserve parr(1 To parrsize1, 1 To (parrsize2 + 1))`  The first number of each dimension is the starting number.  vba thinks you are trying to change the starting numbers also.

Comment: Also - if you want to use `Preserve` then you're restricted to resizing only the last dimension of a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: Thanks Scott. So basic and simple yet I missed it.